# Maintaining a view after navigation to different views in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, viewcontroller

Can anyone tell me how to maintain the state of a view even while navigating through different views. I have a main view controller that has some button interaction and label changes with those interactions and I want to maintain those states while the user navigates to different pages.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to "save" ui object, it is instead better to save the data you want to use somewhere (like a file) and get it when needed